# Logging not logging all scripts

Tags: python, logging

I have a project structured in multiple packages. Some of them are classes, other just have methods. To log, I have this in my main file:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

logging.getLogger('boto3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('botocore').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('s3transfer').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

p = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
fileConfig(f'{p}/logging.ini', defaults={'log_filename': "project.log"})
```

Where `logging.ini` is defined as:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_fileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
suffix="%Y-%m-%d.log"
formatter=formatter
args=('%(log_filename)s','midnight',1,5)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
datefmt=
```

In my main file, I initialize a class called Pipeline, which import multiple scripts and has, in its initialization:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

In the other modules, which are not classes, I simply do:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_method():
    logger.info("Calling my_method()")
```

What I'm not understanding is why, for the "simple" modules, no logs are actually being logged. If I comment the previous line, though, and just do `logging.info(...)`, I get logs for them, with the root key:

```
2020-03-17 16:35:36,072 core.pipeline INFO     _generate_trajectories_heat_map() called.
2020-03-17 16:35:36,337 root         INFO     Drawing image...
2020-03-17 16:35:37,178 root         INFO     Drawing velocities of vehicles...
```

I'm trying to find what I'm missing.
A minimal example can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bfGnikaCng_4N1rR05RYG2G2RcvsQoBP

If you run `main.py`, just the `Pipeline` class will be logged. If you change `mypackage.py` from what it is to:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def method():
    logging.info("Logging method from package.")
```

Everything will be logged.

Comment: You set some of the loggers to level CRITICAL, meaning they will only log critical messages. Maybe these are the ones that fail to log? Just to be sure...

Comment: No, they're not. All critical levels that I set are from pip packages, nothing internal. And to log, as exemplified above, I make sure to use info. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, ok, that would have been obvious... I don't see the problem then - you define only a root logger, and AFAIK, all specific loggers should fall back to that one. Strange...

Comment: I managed to put a minimal example here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bfGnikaCng_4N1rR05RYG2G2RcvsQoBP

Comment: Ok, probably found the problem (see answer). I hadn't used a file config this way before, so I wasn't aware of this, either.